# BigQuery Two Tables (Join?) Name Lookup

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently have two tables on Bigquery where I'm trying to look up the 'english name' of a specific address. Example tables below.

Table1

```
Address|Value
------------------
1111,55
2222,99
8888|33
```

Table2

```
Address|Name
------------------
1111|Bob
2222|Jill
8888|Steven
```

Desired Result after Query

```
Address|Name|Value
------------------
1111|Bob|55
2222|Jill|99
8888|Steven|33
```

Any help to do this in BigQuery would be appreciated.

Real Query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN tablename.from_number = '1231231234' THEN tablename.to_number ELSE tablename.from_number END AS party,
       COUNT(*) AS call_count,
       tablename.caller_address AS caller_address
FROM `bigquery-database` tablename
WHERE '1231231234' in (tablename.from_number, tablename.to_number)
GROUP BY party, caller_address
ORDER by call_count DESC
```

In summary, I'm trying to look up caller_address' first name which resides in another table under tablename2.firstname and display it in the query output. I can't figure out how to use (join?).

Pseudo Code

```
SELECT CASE WHEN tablename.from_number = '1231231234' THEN tablename.to_number ELSE tablename.from_number END AS party,
       COUNT(*) AS call_count,
       tablename.caller_address AS caller_address,

       Find where tablename.caller_address equals db.tablename2.caller_address and display first name from db.tablename2.name

FROM `bigquery-database` tablename
WHERE '1231231234' in (tablename.from_number, tablename.to_number)
GROUP BY party, caller_address
ORDER by call_count DESC
```

Comment: what + have + you + tried + ? this is extremely basic even for newbie - SO is not code service - we are here to help you not to write code for you!

Comment: Heh. I understand. I actually have quite a complex query and this is the most basic I could think of to get the point across. I'll modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple inner join is what you need.

```
select t1.address, t2.name, t1.value
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.address=t2.address
```

[BigQuery Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax?hl=de#join-types)

Comment: Now I'm interested

Comment: most likely PO will notice the problem when run on real data - so let's wait. But in general - quality of question limits quality of answer - so it is not that surprising.

Comment: Real query added.

Comment: @Johann that worked! I did have to modify to "inner join Table2 as t2 on t1.address=t2.address"

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant in all defense...  You're right. I should have provided more detail and I apologize for that. Thank you for helping us newbs out, even if that means getting on us about not providing enough detail!

Comment: lol, you found only one aspect of why it was wrong. I think there is more - but this depends on your real data  - from practical standpoint - i still think it is not fully correct because of type of join

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I didn't want someone to write the full code for me. Just needed the general logic to show me the general way. I troubleshooted the remainder of the problem and so far the results are proving to be accurate. What other join would you recommend?

Comment: you don't need to change anything if it works for you.  but take a look at different types of joins  - like INNER vs LEFT for example. As of my initial comments about writing code for you  - they were made when you had nothing in your question showing that you did any attempts on your own. glad you added something there :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: I assume that the adress in both tables cannot be null, so the inner join is correct for this case. Which join would you use or do you have a completely different solution?

Comment: "address cannot be null" - is "ok" assumption. But address from Table1 very possibly cam be missed in Table2 - so usually in such use-case-pattern left join is used and not inner join - but it is definitely on per use case basis. if inner join perfectly works for OP - which looks like it is - so be it :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant you're absolutely correct here and I ended up using a left join along with where X is not null as I needed the complete set from the table on the left.

Comment: Glad our “chat” helped you. “See” you in next posts

Comment: Thank you @MikhailBerlyant!